# RSA weak padding

Tags: rsa, modular-arithmetic

Suppose to have a function for numbers expressed in 8-bit $\in [0,2^8-1]$ defined as:
$$f(x)=x||x||x||x$$ where $|f(x)|$ is exactly 32 bits.

e.g., suppose x=2 (00000010) so $f(x)=2+2^9+2^{17}+2^{25}=33686018$ (00000010000000100000001000000010)

Given **N** and **x** I'd like to find **y,z,w**  s.t.

$$f(x)*f(y) \space mod \space N= f(z)*f(w) \space mod \space N$$

What is a good way to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OBVIOUS**, if you write $f(x)=(1+2^8+2^{16}+2^{24})\times x=K\times x$.
Then $f(x)\times f(y)=K^2\times x \times y$.
Then $\forall y$, choosing $z \in (\mathbb{Z}/n.\mathbb{Z})^{*}$ allows to dermine the unique $w \in \mathbb{Z}/n.\mathbb{Z}$ satisfying this relation in the multiplicative group.

Comment: Use the table of the multiplicative group. From $K^2\times x \times y\;=\; K^2\times z \times w $ what could you do in a set endowed with a group structure?

Comment: sorry I misclick and delete the original question on the comment that was "how to choose z and w?". So I have just to bring any w and z s.t. $wz=xy$ or is there some other criteria that I am missing?

Comment: Take a look over the to the definition of group structure and understand how to do arithmetric. here if you fix three parameters x, y, and z you can calculate w, exactly as you have to do in elementary school. This is only arithmetic.

Comment: Thanks, but when you write $\mathbb{Z}/n.\mathbb{Z}$ who is $n$ there?

Comment: This is your N. Sorry for the typo.

Comment: Or more simply, find distinct $w$,$y$,$z$ each $\in[0,2^8-1]$ and not equal to $x$ with $x\cdot y=z\cdot w$; which is easy except if $x$ is prime an at least $131$.

Comment: @fgrieu, the concept of prime don't exist in Z/nZ. However there is a theory in algebraic number theory with ring of integer $\mathcal{O}_K$, very interesting.

Comment: Your $f(x)=(1+2^8+2^{16}+2^{24})\times x=K\times x$ is restricted to $x$ an at-most-8-bit element of $\mathbb N$, and has $K$ and $f(x)$ in $\mathbb N$, is not it?

Comment: @fgrieu, Yes it' parts of the asumption. x is 8-bits integer, for a large modulus N,  I presume as OP want to experiment weak paddings.